# the log file in docker of flink

Tags: docker, logging, apache-flink

I'm using the flink-1.4.0 docker like:

```
version: '3'
services:
  jobmanager:
    image: ${FLINK_DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME:-flink}
    expose:
      - "6123"
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    command: jobmanager
    volumes:
      - /home/yeyunlong/work/flink/flink-jar:/var/log/mongodb
    environment:
      - JOB_MANAGER_RPC_ADDRESS=jobmanager

  taskmanager:
    image: ${FLINK_DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME:-flink}
    expose:
      - "6121"
      - "6122"
    depends_on:
      - jobmanager
    command: taskmanager
    links:
      - "jobmanager:jobmanager"
    environment:
      - JOB_MANAGER_RPC_ADDRESS=jobmanager
```

In the docker, the dir /opt/flink/log is empty. but use `docker logs $(containerId)` , I can get all of the log information.

What should I do to make the log in `/opt/flink/log`. Thank you!

Comment: I had set `env.log.dir: /opt/flink/log`  in flink-conf.yaml

Comment: the first line of `docker logs $(containerId)` is `Starting taskmanager as a console application on host 4f5aa3f4b7ca.` ;  Maybe the console application is the keyword.

Comment: -  JVM Options:
-     -Xms1024M
-     -Xmx1024M
-     -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=8388607T
-     -Dlog4j.configuration=file:/opt/flink/conf/log4j-console.properties
-     -Dlogback.configurationFile=file:/opt/flink/conf/logback-console.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using [docker-flink](https://github.com/docker-flink/docker-flink) images which use bin/flink-console.sh to launch the JM or TM. That script relies on settings in conf/log4j-console.properties.

I use the docker-compose.yaml below to set my own version of the Log4j properties file. From the docker-compose.yaml, I can set the file to use and from the properties file of Log4j control the output.

```
version: "2.1"

services:
  jobmanager:
    image: flink
    expose:
      - "6123"
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    command: jobmanager
    volumes:
      - /c/Users/XYZ/playground/flink/shared/log4j.properties:/opt/flink/conf/log4j-console.properties
    environment:
      - JOB_MANAGER_RPC_ADDRESS=jobmanager
      - FLINK_ENV_JAVA_OPTS=-Dlog.file=/opt/flink/log/jobmanager.log

  taskmanager:
    image: flink
    expose:
      - "6121"
      - "6122"
    depends_on:
      - jobmanager
    command: taskmanager
    links:
      - jobmanager:jobmanager
    volumes:
      - /c/Users/XYZ/playground/flink/shared/log4j.properties:/opt/flink/conf/log4j-console.properties
    environment:
      - JOB_MANAGER_RPC_ADDRESS=jobmanager
      - FLINK_ENV_JAVA_OPTS=-Dlog.file=/opt/flink/log/taskmanager.log
```

Comment: thanks for you help. I get you point.The key word is log4j.properties.I change the setting and then it works.